# How to fetch security settings from a google api

Tags: google-api

I implement an application which will check workspaces connected to it either they are compliant or not to my rules. For that reason, I need:

1. Password security policy. I see that those settings exist in the admin console(Security -> Password Management) but I couldn't find any API method which allows me to fetch them to my application. How can I fetch those password policy settings?
2. 2-Step Verification settings. Those settings are available in the admin console(Security -> 2-Step Verification) but I couldn't find any api method for that. How can I fetch it?